# How to register C# text service with windows 8 Text service Framework?

Tags: c#, text, com, microsoft-metro

I have have developed a keyboard(C#) with different layouts and also suggest some words on entering on TextBox but it is still in the application level i would like to integrate it with TSF which makes my keyboard available through out windows 8. I figured out that i need to register the Text service with TSF in (in-proc server).I am stuck here it would be great if you can give me some pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, you cannot replace the default touch keyboard with a custom implementation.

See...
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winappswithcsharp/thread/3c301e8a-a141-499b-b0ee-37c7512a18ab